# LogCat is full of "input svInfo.flags is 8" while the app is running

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, logcat

When I run almost any app in Android Studio, my [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) gets full of messages like:

> "? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8 
> ? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8"

What's this? Is there something wrong about my app?

Comment: Are you running the app in Emulator?

Comment: I see the same thing.  Wondering what it is.  The are at the ERROR log level.

Comment: Turning off Location from device (emulator) Settings solved this issue for me.

Comment: Either you should give permission for location or manually turned off from Emulator

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should create Virtual Device in AVD manager without GPS sensor.

[image: new device]

and uncheck GPS

[image: uncheck GPS]

Errors will gone.

Comment: That's unfortunately no solution if the app relies on GPS being switched on. My app reacts differently if GPS is switched off or not available at all.

Answer (score 56):

There is a much simpler solution. in your AVD simply go to `settings->location` and uncheck `use location`.
[image: Location service image]

Comment: Brilliant! THIS is the best answer. I don't know why it's activated if it's only throwing errors.

Comment: Thanks. Easy solution : )

Comment: And what if an application requires location? See [@vlz solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63508793/2914140).

Answer (score 14):

I needed GPS enabled and could not disable Location Services, so I used this regex with a negative lookahead in logcats search filter:

`^(?!.*input svInfo\.flags is 8)`

This selects everything not containing the end of the error message ("input svInfo.flags is 8"), but displays everything else.

The search filter should be right above the log output. You might need to activate a selct box reading "regex".

Answer (score 4):

Not likely anything wrong with your app. The problem is probably the settings in the "Filter Configuration" in Logcat. It kinda hides as a setting, and has a habit of automatically switching to the "No Filters" selection. If you find out why, let me know.

To ignore the debug error in your question: in the Logcat panel  choose a configure filter option in the drop-down after the filter input and Regex option checkbox.

Probably best option is "Show only selected application".

Answer (score 4):

It really solved the problem when you turn off your location services.
It happens when I try to fetch data from web API, now I resolve by turning off location.

Answer (score 2):

Exiting and removing the app from multitask in the emulator and rerunning from Android Studio fixed it for me.

I'm assuming it’s an Android Studio bug.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how you did that?

Comment: 1. launch program, I have AVD the android emulator for Nexus5x API 29, 2.Log cat gives a bunch of errors, 3. In the emulator click on bottom right of the phone screen(the multi task square button). 4.click and drag the screen up(removes from multitask). 5. drag up on screen to view apps 6.open your app. At this point the errors went away for me. if it didn't work try deleting the app from the phone. You can also try going to file->Invalidate caches /Restart and also try Build->Clean project. As well turning your computer on and off can sometimes fix IDE problems.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, you can disable the message in [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) by going to the *Terminal* tab in Android Studio, and then [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to your SDK location platform tools, which is usually at

```
cd C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Then you can set the visibility, so with standard settings you don’t see the message:

```
.\adb shell setprop log.tag.GnssHAL_GnssInterface S
```

The solution is mostly from ChatGPT.

This applies basically to any logtag. Just change the thing behind the *log.tag* to the logtag that you don’t want to see. Then you can also disable visibility in standard installations.

Comment: ChatGPT content is strictly prohibited.

Comment: Well, at least the text wasn't from ChatGPT.

Comment: didn't know that, but why? :D
Actually, only the commands are from chatgpt

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible solution to this fix,

Either

> You can disable Location Services in the Emulator that you are running app

or

> Create a new Virtual device and disable **GPS** inside Hardware Profile