# Logcat keep pushing Error "input svInfo.flags is 8"

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, logcat

Logcat is constantly show error : "E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8"

my app use Location so turn it off is not a proper solution for me.

what is the reason for it ? and what the solution? thanks.

Comment: Is the app running properly

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63508793/876267) may help.

Comment: it didnt helped because i do need my GPS services..